# How set a page to maximum and minimum sizes via css

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm creating a page that looks like this:

[image: page layout]

Here is the code

```
body { min-height: 50vh;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#headlogo{
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-weight: bold;}
#header {
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #1565C0;
}
#header .section {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 900px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#header .section ul {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 50px 0 10px;
}
#header .section ul li {
    background: url(./images/headernav.gif) no-repeat top right;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
}
#header .section ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 8px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.03em;
}
#header .section ul li a:hover {
    background: url(./images/headernavselected.gif) no-repeat top right;
}
#header .section ul li.selected {
    background: url(./images/headernavselected.gif) no-repeat top right;
}
#header .section ul li.selected a {
    background: url(./images/headernavselected.gif) no-repeat top left;
    color: #E3F2FD;
}


#body {
    margin: 0 0;
    background-color:#DEDEDE;
}
#body .section {
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 800px;
    width: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    padding: 60px 100px 50px 100px;
    min-height: 50vh
}
#footer {
    background: #1565C0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#footer .section {
    margin: 0 auto ;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
};


<div id="header">
    <div class="section">

            <a href="index.html" id="headlogo"><img src="./images/headerlogo.png" width="340" height="110" alt="" title=""></a>
        <ul>
            <li class="selected">
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="about.html">Store</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="hairstyle.html">Products</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="news.html">Forum</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="contact.html">Support</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="body">
    <div class="section">
    Lorem ipsum

</div>
</div>


<div id="footer">
    <div class="section">
            &copy; copyright 2023 | all rights reserved.
</div>
```

The CSS is available here:

http://jsfiddle.net/85L448ds/

But I don't know how to make the page more responsive to sizing inconsistency. **I want the page to default to 800 pixels wide, except where there is wide content or the browser window is too small (it should have a gray background outside this area). Whereas the height should be such that the height should not be less than the browser height.**

In other words, I'd like it to work something like:

```
Width = 800
If Width > Window_Width then
  Width = Window_Width 
If Content_Width > Width then
  Width = Content_Width
```

Whereas height should be the greater of: Content_Height and Windows_Height.

Note: Content_Width/Height cannot be predicted because I have a forum where the table structure is sometimes oversize to accomodate large images.

I've tried setting the CSS min-width property to 800, but that makes the default width 100%.

I thought height would be easy, just need to set the body to 100% height or 100vh, but that seems to have no effect...

Comment: Have you looked at CSS media queries to allow different CSS values for different screen/browser sizes?

Comment: doesn't `html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0}` fix your problem?

Comment: i updated answer let me know if i done anything wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run snippet in full page and then play with window size after reduce the size of window your menu will hide and one button you can see. now show menu on button click.

> If you run snippet so at first time you can see button because your
>   window size is < 768px if you want see menu then see result in full page

for responsive site use width in % not in px.

and you can also use bootstrap for that.

```css
body {
  min-height: 50vh;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.smallButton{
     display:none
   
}
#headlogo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#header {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #1565C0;
  width:100%;
  height: 90px;
}
#header .section {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#header .section ul {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 50px 0 10px;
}
#header .section ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 0;
}
#header .section ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 8px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.03em;
}
#header .section ul li a:hover {
  background: url(./images/headernavselected.gif) no-repeat top right;
}
#header .section ul li.selected {
  background: url(./images/headernavselected.gif) no-repeat top right;
}
#header .section ul li.selected a {
  background: url(./images/headernavselected.gif) no-repeat top left;
  color: #E3F2FD;
}
#body {
  margin: 0 0;
  background-color: #DEDEDE;
  width:100%
    
}

#footer {
  background: #1565C0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width:100%;
  
}
#footer .section {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
@media (max-width: 768px)
{
  #header .section ul {
      display:none
   }
  .smallButton{
    display:block;
     position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 32px;
  }
  #body .section {
     margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 500px;
    height: 700px;
    position: relative;
}
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
  #body .section {
     margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 800px;
    height: 700px;
    position: relative;
}

}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="section">

    <a href="index.html" id="headlogo">
    </a>
    <button class="smallButton">---</button>
    <ul>
      <li class="selected">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="about.html">Store</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="hairstyle.html">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="news.html">Forum</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="contact.html">Support</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="body">
  <div class="section">
    Lorem ipsum

  </div>
</div>


<div id="footer">
  <div class="section">
    &copy; copyright 2023 | all rights reserved.
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that makes the page width 100% at all times. I want the page locked to 800px wide (with grey borders each side), except for situations where content is wider than 800, or page is less than 800.

Comment: @Xaz i updated answer you can see if screen size is less then 786 then #body  section is 500px with gray borer and if screen size is greater then 786 then section is 800px . and in this example header and footer are not fixed and body doesn't have that much containt so i hard coded height if you want any help regarding fix header and footer and body part let me know will help you :D

Comment: Thanks Keval, that works well. Is there any way to make the "page" (white area) widen if the content of the page is wide. For example if I enter <PRE>**200 characters**</PRE> (to mimic a page with a wide image) the right-most text is chopped off. It should instead widen the page and add a scroll bar (if necessary)

Comment: @xaz You know how to accept answer ? :D  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Hi Keval, yes, I do, but I was hoping to fully solve my problem. A big issue is that many of my pages are unavoidably wide (because I have a forum where users can insert images). Using the supplied solutions those wide pages are cut off, and the user cannot scroll to see the content. Is there no solution to that in CSS?

Comment: @Xaz yes you can solve problem note one thing when you develop site responsive then  provide width in % . or for responsive site use [Bootstarp](http://getbootstrap.com/) . if you use bootstrap then place image in bootstrap model and if you not using bootstrap then share your code will help you :D

Answer (score 1):

I believe CSS Media Queries will resolve your problem.

Of course it is possibly just one of the solutions, but it is purely CSS and really easy to manage.

**For more information about media queries:** http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Using media queries happens like in this following example, where your `#headLogo` is set to change its properties once the viewport width is less or equal to 768px:

```
@media (max-width: 768px)
{
   #headLogo {
      text-align: center;
      max-width: 300px;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/85L448ds/2/)

You don't actually need media queries for that

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

will make body occupy all available space in window. It will shrink and expand with window re-size.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. The page height is less than the available window height (i.e. there is a border at the bottom). Also the width is always 100%. I want the page locked to 800px wide (with grey borders each side), except when content is wider than 800, or page is less than 800.