# bootstrap dropdown-menu-right when screen too small

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown menu and using

class = dropdown-menu

the dropdown menu uses extra space on the right site. If I make the screen smaller (or use a mobile device) there might not be any space on the right site. In this case I can use

class = dropdown-menu-right

which uses the space on the left site instead. 
My question is, is there a way to detect the size of the screen and based on that render a html template with one of the two options above?
thanks
carl

Comment: Can you show the code, what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution using media Query only css**

> Note: Run code in full screen and try to reduce screen

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .one {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red
  }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .two {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: yellow
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="one two "></div>
```

see this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33209805/4696809  in this answer run snippet in full screen you can see menu if you reduce window size menu will gone and button will appear even i am changing center part also depending upon window size

**Using Jquery**

> Note: Run code in full screen and try to reduce screen and see console
>   and div.if you reduce screen width div color will change.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    var width = $(window).width()
    console.log($(window).width())
    if (width > 786) {
      console.log("BIg")
        $('.first').removeClass('new')
    } else if (width < 786) {
      console.log("small")
       $('.first').addClass('new')
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.first {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
.new{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first"></div>
```

Comment: OP needs to change class based on screen width, how would you do it using CSS (media queries)? Wouldn't it involve JS / jQuery for it?

Comment: it is possible with media query also and js also

Comment: For CSS you will require to add two separate dropdowns with different class. While with jQuery, you can just replace the class.

Comment: yes that is right ,  but instead of  two separate dropdowns use one  dropdown and  apply two class  in it like in  given example. see my first snippet may be it will help op :D